# Cannot find the tag library descriptor for /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, struts-tags

I am new to the Struts framework and while developing a simple Struts 2 application I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find the tag library descriptor for /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

`struts-html.tld` is a TLD for Struts 1 tags.

Struts 2 uses a single TLD, `struts-tags.tld`, and it's in the `struts2-core-2.x.x.jar`.

You can declare it as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

There are other TLDs like `struts-dojo-tags` (deprecated in 2.1), `struts-jquery-tags`, etc... but start with the main one, take a tour of Struts2 and then eventually try to use the "extensions".

Comment: (The Dojo tags were *deprecated* in 2.1, but existed in 2.0. And still exist now :(

Comment: As usual, thanks @Dave :D (off topic: I've read some post of you in the Struts3 thread on nabble... when is it supposed to be released ?)

Comment: I have no idea yet--I think we're still figuring out what we want it to look like. I have a few things I'd like to add, but as usual, timing/availability is an issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Can not find the tag library descriptor

For above Error.

Please upload the Struts 2 core jar file to the Build path of your application/web project, it works.

Thanks 
Ghouse khan.